# How to get the index of the result of nltk.RegexpParser?

Tags: regex, nlp, nltk

I want to get not only result of RegexpParser, but also the index of the result. 
For example the start index of the word and the end index of the word.

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
text = word_tokenize("6 ACCESSKEY attribute can be used to specify many 6.0 shortcut key 6.0")
tag = pos_tag(text)

print tag

# grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN|NNS|NNP|NNPS>}"
grammar2 = """Triple: {<CD>*<DT>?<CD>*<JJ>*<CD>*<VBD|VBG>*<CD>*<NN.*>+<CD>*<MD>*<VB.*>+<JJ>?<RB>?<CD>*<DT>?<NN.*>*<IN*|TO*>?<DT>?<CD>*<JJ>*<CD>*<VBD|VBG>*<CD>*<NN.*>+<CD>*}
              Triple: {<CD>*<DT>?<CD>*<JJ>*<CD>*<VBD|VBG>*<CD>*<NN.*>+<CD>*<MD>*<VB.*>+<JJ>?<RB>?<CD>*<DT>?<NN.*>*<TO>?<VB><DT>?<CD>*<JJ>*<CD>*<VBD|VBG>*<CD>*<NN.*>+<CD>*}
              """

grammar = """
                NP: {<CD>*<DT>?<CD>*<JJ>*<CD>*<VBD|VBG>*<CD>*<NN.*>+<CD>*}
                VP: {<VB.*>+<JJ>*<RB>*<JJ>*<VB.*>?<DT>?<NN|NP>?<IN*|TO*>?}
                """
cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
result = cp.parse(tag)
print(result)

result.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you give the parser tokenised text, there is no way it can guess the original offsets (how could it know how much space was between the tokens).
But, fortunately, the `parse()` method accepts additional info, which is simply passed on to the output.

In your example, the input (you saved it in the badly named variable `tag`) looks like this:

```
[('6', 'CD'),
 ('ACCESSKEY', 'NNP'),
 ('attribute', 'NN'),
 ...
```

If you manage to change it to

```
[('6', 'CD', 0, 1),
 ('ACCESSKEY', 'NNP', 2, 11),
 ('attribute', 'NN', 12, 21),
 ...
```

and feed this to the parser, then the offsets will be included in the parse tree:

```
Tree('S',
     [Tree('NP', [('6', 'CD', 0, 1),
                  ('ACCESSKEY', 'NNP', 2, 11),
                  ('attribute', 'NN', 12, 21)]),
      ...
```

How do you get the offsets into the tagged sequence?
Well, I will leave this as a programming exercise to you.
Hint: Look for the `span_tokenize()` method of the word tokenisers.

Comment: Actually I can get the offsets, it's not so difficult. Any way thank you very much!